# launch4j compiled java application executable being blocked by antivirus

Tags: java, exe, executable-jar, launch4j

I am trying to create an installer for my Java Application. I searched online and found out about **Launch4j** and **Inno Setup.**

After compiling exe using Launch4j, it doesn't seem to work. I am using windows and .exe's not really executing, it wasn't listed on taskmanager as well. After some fiddling and trying out stuff, found out that it was Avast. After turning of Avast shields, it worked like charmed.

I found out that the ***executable itself was the one being blocked***, and not launch4j while compiling resulting to some convoluted .exe beyond my understanding. (*by trying to compile when avast is on and off, and both .exe only runs when avast is off*)

Have any of you guys encountered this? What if it will be blocked by other antivirus as well? Is there any possible *explanations* and/or *solutions*? Place to start looking into?

Afaik, my code doesn't really do suspicious operations. I tried some simple gui app that show only a label inside a frame and still, same thing happens.

Comment: Upload the `exe` to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/) and report results. I remember some obscure antivirus reported a false positive for my Launch4j wrapper.

Comment: ohh. ok, thanks! follow up question though? After I have uploaded it, do I have to update my antivirus for it to take effect? does that mean, it won't run on any machine prior to submission at VirusTotal?

Comment: VirusTotal will only check the file against multiple antiviruses, not much else. You can use it to make sure that your antivirus is actually reporting a false positive. You did obtain Launch4j from a trusted source (eg. official site), right?

Comment: yes, I did. I downloaded it from their official site. what do you mean _"will only check the file against multiple antiviruses"_? VirusTotal will inform only the common antiviruses that my .exe is a false positive? My really concern is, what if my client haven't updated their antivirus software yet? Do i have to inform them to do so beforehand?

Comment: Having issues here with the exe files created by Launch4j 3.11 and Symantec 12.1.6... anyway this antivirus is often quarantining prefectly normal programs and letting the real threats pass through :/

Answer (score 1):

It turns out, This was the actual reason:

> launch4j while compiling resulting to some convoluted .exe
>   beyond my understanding.

The latest build of launch4j has issues on it's headers being flagged by VirusTotal and some other antivirus software when it compiles an exe.

While reading the discussion board on launch4j's official site, I stumbled upon [Balthasar Gregovic's comments](http://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/discussion/332683/thread/d5baedac/#6abf) saying that the then 3.7 has issues but not the 3.5 verion. I downloaded the said version, and it worked like a charm. I think it would be wise to use launch4j version 3.5 for now. I will try to comment on the said discussion board and inform them that 3.8 also has the same issue.